# EXCEL rank.eq function: rank numbers in a row in relation to other numbers of the same assigned category

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, ranking-functions

MY Spreadsheet was made using Excel 2016. I have a table with different numbers with assigned categories:

| Size | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | solid |
| 12 | liquid |
| 11 | liquid |
| 7 | liquid |
| 9 | solid |

I want to return the rank of the numbers, but only rank them based on other numbers in the same category like this:

| Size | Category | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | solid | 1 |
| 12 | liquid | 1 |
| 11 | liquid | 2 |
| 7 | liquid | 3 |
| 9 | solid | 2 |

My current solution that accomplishes this requires me to add two new rows for each category:

| Size | Category | rank *=IF(liquid rank<>"",liquid rank,IF(solid rank<>"",solid rank))* | liquid size *=IF(category="liquid",size,"")* | liquid rank *=IF(liquid size="","",RANK.EQ(liquid size,liquid size))* | solid size *=IF(category="solid",size,"")* | solid rank *=IF(solid size="","",RANK.EQ(solid size,solid size))* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | solid | 1 |  |  | 11 | 1 |
| 12 | liquid | 1 | 12 | 1 |  |  |
| 11 | liquid | 2 | 11 | 2 |  |  |
| 7 | liquid | 3 | 7 | 3 |  |  |
| 9 | solid | 2 |  |  | 9 | 2 |

Is there a way to have all the calculations happening in the additional rows be run inside the RANK row and thus get rid of them? Or is there a more elegant solution as a whole?

Comment: my actual spreadsheet has about 24 categories, the function in rank was stupidly big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B6,B2:B6)-COUNTIFS(A2:A6,"<"&A2:A6,B2:B6,B2:B6)
```

I suppose the Excel-2016 variant to drag down would be:

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$6,B2)-COUNTIFS(A$2:A$6,"<"&A2,B$2:B$6,B2)
```

Comment: If you have two or more identical Size value of the same Category this formula gives an incorrect result. If you take it into consideration will works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `COUNTIFS()`.

```
 =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,$B2)
```

[image]

Comment: this only works with sorted lists, it breaks if you change the 12 into a 8 for example